# Shell script to replace a variable in a HTML document

Tags: html, templates, shell, sed, awk

I want to generate a static website from a shell script.

A example for the shell script code is:

```
author="Github INC."
name="Github"
description="social coding"
text=$(awk '{ print }' main.html)
```

The main.html could look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>$name</title> 
</head> 
<body>
......
```

I want to replace the $name string in the html document between the title tag with the $name string in the bash script (in this example Github) so in this example it **should** look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Github</title> 
</head> 
<body>
......
```

I could do this by changing the shell script Code to this:

```
author="Github INC."
name="Github"
description="social coding"
text="$( sed "s/<title>.*<\/title>/<title>$name<\/title>" main.html )"
```

But if I use more then one string in the html document, then it won't work anymore...

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>$name</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" /> 
    <meta name="author" content="$author" /> 
    <meta name="description" content="$description" /> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /> 
</head> 
<body>
```

Any ideas how to connect the strings from the Shell Script with the HTML Document?

Comment: How should I do this with awk???

Comment: not sure what @RobW means. `sed 's/1/2/g;s/a/b/g;s/txt/newTxt/g'` allows you to change as many lines as you want. Typically for more than a couple of sed cmds (more than my example above), people put all of the sed actions into a seperate file, 1 cmd per line, and then execute like `sed -f mySedFixer.sed myTest.html.template > myTest.html` Or if your workin in Linux, see if you sed supports the  `-i` option, which saves modifications to the named file(s) without need to redirect into a temporary file, and rename. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter By "works on a single line only", I was referring to the fact that `sed` processes input line by line.

Answer (score 5):

Using `awk`

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat html.sh 
#!/bin/bash
author="Github INC."
name="Github"
description="social coding"
awk '{sub(/\$name/,name);sub(/\$author/,author);sub(/\$description/,description);}1' name="$name" author="$author" description="$description" inputfile
```

Using `sed`

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat html1.sh 
#!/bin/bash
author="Github INC."
name="Github"
description="social coding"
sed -e '/\$name/s//"$name"/' -e '/\$description/s//"$description"/' -e '/\$author/s//"$author"/' inputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

see the test (with awk) below: actually sed should work as well.

```
kent$  cat main.html 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>$name</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" /> 
    <meta name="author" content="$author" /> 
    <meta name="description" content="$description" /> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /> 
</head> 
<body>


kent$  cat doIt.sh 
#!/bin/bash
author="Github INC."
name="Github"
description="social coding"
awk -vauthor="$author" -vname="$name" -vdesc="$description" '{gsub(/\$name/,name);gsub(/\$author/,author);gsub(/\$description/,desc)}1' main.html

kent$  ./doIt.sh  
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Github</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" /> 
    <meta name="author" content="Github INC." /> 
    <meta name="description" content="social coding" /> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /> 
</head> 
<body>
```

Answer (score 1):

### vim:

```
:%s/\v"\zs\$\w+\ze"/\={'$author':'Github INC.', '$name':'Github', '$description':'social coding'}[submatch(0)]/g
```

Answer (score 0):

I created [shtpl](https://github.com/zstegi/shtpl) for that purpose. (A very young project of mine, but may you want to give it a try, because i think it solves exactly your needs)

To replace in your last example all placeholders, you can simply execute:

```
$ name=testname author=testauthor description=mydescription sh -c "$( shtpl example.html.tpl )"
```

The result would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>testname</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" /> 
    <meta name="author" content="testauthor" /> 
    <meta name="description" content="mydescription" /> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /> 
</head> 
<body>
```

It's that easy.

Answer (score -1):

The following snippet can be used to replace `$name` with `Github`:

```
# Example: Replace $name in main.html with Github, output in replaced.html
title=Github
awk '{ gsub("\$name","'$title'")}; print $0 }' main.html > replaced.html
```

The replaced file is output at replaced.html. If you want to overwrite the existing file, use:

```
awk '{ gsub("\$name","'$title'")}; print $0 }' main.html > replaced.html &&
     mv replaced.html test.html
```